# how can I allow outgoing access to a port in firewall

Tags: linux, firewall

Im doing a `file_get_contents` but getting `Connection refused`

I used the following to allow outgoing connections from server2 to server1, and vice-versa. But I'm still getting `failed to open stream: Connection refused`

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 123.123.123.123 --dport 8983 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp -s 321.321.321.321 --dport 8983 -j ACCEPT
```

Maybe there's some rule where i cant use `file_get_contents` between two different servers/ip?

I think for now i'll use `curl`, but interested to know what's not working here...

Comment: Connection refused could also means refused by the other end (the server you're connecting to). Are you sure the server accepts connection on that port?

Comment: In my experience, "connection refused" has invariably come down to not having anything listening to the receiving port on the remote host. Have you verified that a daemon or service is listening to port 8983 on the remote host?

If this were a firewall issue, chances are the firewall would have silently dropped the packets and your clue would have been request timeouts on the client side.

Answer (score 3):

You are connecting to port 8983 on destination, so you must allow output traffic to that port on `server 2`, which you are:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 123.123.123.123 --dport 8983 -j ACCEPT
```

You should also accept incoming traffic on `server 2` for related and established connections in general:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Also, don't forget to add the corresponding rules on `server 1`:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8983 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

If you are still unable to connect after setting this rules, you are probably being blocked by an intermediate firewall between `server 1` and `server 2`.

If that's not the case, maybe `server 1` is behind a NAT and you have to set the NAT router to forward incoming connections to 8983 to the same port on `server 1` behind that router.